# Cordova app keep localstorage data in new app version?

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, webview

I'm developing an Cordova app using Cordova 3.5, and I have a question about data storage. How to keep data alive in new app version? Can I just use LocalStorage or WebSQL? or I need some others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the localstorage is persistent. if you update the app all the saved key-value-pairs are still there.
but if you delete the app and reinstall it again they are gone!
WebSQL - i dont know!

But why dont you try it on your own?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried with debug apk build by Cordova, but I don't sure that is same with updating app by GooglePlay or not.

Comment: Since iOS 5 the localStorage may not be persistent. If you are running out of space, your localStorage may be cleared by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating my app on play store and some user reporting that their data gone after updating (I got a lot of 1 star and bad reviews because of that).

So now I store the data in file on SD CARD or in the cloud. Big performance hit.